# How to perform regression analysis in Spark MLlib for churn determination in telecom industry?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, decision-tree, apache-spark-mllib

I am working on `churn` prediction(whether a customer move to another company) in telecom industry using `decision tree`(`supervised learning`). I have a dataset with following structure(`csv` data):

```
number vmail messages,total call minutes,total number of calls,total call charge,number of customer service calls,churn
```

In this the last column (`churn`) is a `true` or `false` value column and serves as a label. During testing I want to predict the values for this column (either as true-false or 0-1). My doubt is that how can I train the data using `Spark MLlibs` `decision tree` algorithm? I was going through the `regression example` given in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-decision-tree.html) and I am unable to understand as where are they providing the `labels` during the training phase. The example has:

```
val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()
val impurity = "variance"
val maxDepth = 5
val maxBins = 32

val model = DecisionTree.trainRegressor(trainingData, categoricalFeaturesInfo, impurity,
  maxDepth, maxBins)
```

Since it is a supervised learning shouldn't we be providing the labels as well when training the model?

How can I train my model on my data with providing the `labels` and then test to predict the `labels` for the test data?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as what you are trying to do is a supervised learning, particularly a classification problem. The input the DecisionTree is expecting is a LabeledPoint. LabeledPoint is basically the structure saying which is your target variable (label) and your features vector check here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint

So you use this as an input, you can also split the LabeledPoint if you want like training and testing, or do a loop for cv or anything needed.

What is important is that you map your true/false cases into 1/0 before you train and that this:

```
val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()
```

is used for telling the model which of your features are categorical, for example lets say feature 1 and 2 only are categorical, then you should write it as:

```
val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]((1,2),(2,4))
```

this is saying feature 1 is categorical and has 2 levels, feature 2 is categorical and has 4 levels. Index here start from 0!!. And you should map all your categorical features before to something like 0,1,2,3...numberLevels.

Example of a LabeledPoint, basically you map your data, this one assumes your values are Double, and you are selecting 1 as your LAbeledPoint, and 2,3 as features.

```
val data = dataInput.rdd.map(x => LabeledPoint(x.getDouble(1),Vectors.dense(x.getDouble(2), x.getDouble(3)))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: So in case of my case none of my features (all columns except the churn column) are categorical. The churn has true/false(or 0/1) value but it is for the label purpose. So, for me what should be the `categoricalFeaturesInfo`? Also, in the example given in the Spark documentation where are they forming the `LabeledPoint` with labels and feature vector?

Comment: If you have no categorical then as in the first case with the empty bracket Map[Int, Int]().  You want an example of LabeledPoint I edit it up there

Comment: Can you also provide me how can I map true/false value of a particular column read from a csv file to 0/1 in Spark with python?

Comment: Also the code(LabledPoint example) you have provided seems to be for Scala right.How wold you do that in python?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the transformations you do to your `csv` data after you read it, but you should do something like this in order to convert it to `LabeledPoint` as @DrVComas was pointing out.

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

def parseCsvLine(line):
    fl = line.split(',')
    l = len(fl)
    return LabeledPoint(fl[l-1], fl[0:l-1])
```

And then the training data you pass to the decision tree should be mapped like this,

```
trainingData = rawData.map(parseCsvLine)
```

Hope it helps.